# How to add the same node multiple times, with different information? (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a program which notifies me when a new episode of one of my series is uploaded, I have a built-in notification center, which stores the uploads. 
How I did this, was basically making a VBox, the NotificationPanel, then having a nLayout with basic things like a close-button, and every time I there is a new episode uploaded, add the nLayout with different name and text for each serie. But I've seen that this isn't "possible", because I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = VBox@2168def7
```

Anyone knows how I can get this to work?

Comment: Create a new object and add it, instead of adding an existing one. (If you want a more detailed answer, you will need a more detailed question, including some code.)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "create a new object"? Could you do some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the same node multiple times.
Just create a new instance of your NotificationPanel for every notification

Comment: Could you give me an example on how'd you go about that?

Answer (score 0):

As comments say, you can't add the same instance of a class multiple times in your VBox.

Each time you catch your event (episode uploaded) what you can do is :

1. Retrieve your VBox
2. Create a new instance of a JavaFX container (for example : HBox, TextField, TextArea, TreeView etc...)
3. Populate this instance with information you want to show
4. Add this instance in you VBox

Btw, by doing this, you don't use the fancy Model-View binding mechanism of JavaFX. A better solution would be to have a model class with an ObservableList in which you could push an instance of an object made to contain the information of the uploaded episode,
and bind this ObservableList to a ListView with a custom CellFactory to build the cells of your List the way you want.

You can find information about the binding mechanism here : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm

You can find information about ListView and custom CellFactory here : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly you should probably create your own custom Node. For example by

```
public class EpisodeBox extends Vbox {
     public EpisodeBox(String name){
           getChildren().add(new Label(name));
           getChildren().add(new Button("Close"));
           // ... etc.
     }
}
```

As Kwoinkwoin stated you can then on each event create a new EpisodeBox and add this one to your Panel.

Comment: I don't need to create a new one, I mean, this works perfectly fine with checkboxes, but not with the HBox, I just want to know how I can add a new one.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. Maybe you should post the code you have so far